# Scoring attempt in ice hockey slang

Tags: slang, sports

Please spell me that word which ice hockey commentators use when a player tries to score. For me it sounds like [vimaunt].

Example: https://youtu.be/53Gu1JsOmGI on the first seconds (00:02).

I’ve spent an hour in discovery of the hockey slang, no results.

P.S. I’m not sure what this word means and is it specific for ice hockey.

Answer (score 2):

**Rebound.**

> 'Rebound' is a term used in sports to describe the ball (or puck or
> other object of play) becoming available for possession by either
> opponent after an attempt to put the ball or puck into the goal has
> been unsuccessful.

Somebody left the correct answer under my question, but the comment was deleted for some reason.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Fyi, rebound is used in football (soccer) and basketball too.

Comment: The comment was probably deleted because answers are not supposed to go into comments.

Comment: I'm not sure who wrote that, but it's not entirely correct. For example, in many sports a scoring attempt simply deflected or blocked by a non-goalie wouldn't produce a "rebound". Usually the shot must hit either the goaltender (if one exists) or the goal (net, backboard, pipes, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a transcription service, but the first 4 seconds appear to me to be:
5 on 5
Brower (?) with a long shot.
Rebound
Oh well saved.